# onclick event not working on dynamically created <li>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, onclick

I have a component where upon aura:iteration (data loaded from server onInit), other components are created (list items of an SLDS lookup). The issue I have is, the onclick on the LI does not fire when I click on any of these items. I have a breakpoint on the first line of the controller function, but it never goes there. Any ideas why is this happening?

++ Since it's a lookup , the list can change when the user enters text in the input

```
<aura:component >

<aura:attribute name="programName" type="String" required="true" />
<aura:attribute name="programId" type="String" required="true" />
<aura:attribute name="associatedAcademicPathways" type="Object[]" required="true" />

 <li onclick="{!c.addElementToAssociatedPathways}">
     <div id="option1" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
         <span class="slds-media__figure">
             <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account">
                 <lightning:icon size="small" iconName="standard:product" alternativeText=""/>
             </span>
         </span>
         <span class="slds-media__body">
             <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{!v.programName}</span>                             
         </span>
     </div>
 </li>
</aura:component>
```

Controller function:

```
addElementToAssociatedPathways : function(component, event, helper){

    var programName = component.get("v.programName");
    var programId = component.get("v.programId");

    var associatedAcademicPathways = component.get('v.associatedAcademicPathways');
    associatedAcademicPathways.push({Name: programName, Id: programId});
    component.set('v.associatedAcademicPathways', associatedAcademicPathways);
}
```

Comment: If this is the only code part then this is all good, no issues.

Comment: I thought so too. Event just doesn't fire. Can't figure out why it wont go to controller function..

Comment: Do you see any error in console?